# How to use stored procedure in execute sql task to find the error exception

Tags: ssis

I created a Data Flow task with a table in SQL Server. I want to add execute SQL task to Data Flow task to give me error message and details of the error in case the data flow task is not success. For this I want to create a query in stored procedure and use in the execute sql task as it is a repetitive job. 
So kindly help me to create a query in general to find if there is error and its details and how to use in execute sql task.

Thank you!